# Django and DataTables ignoring Read, Edit, Delete buttons after initial 10 results

Tags: django, datatables

I am using Django with DataTables and it is working fine, except for one part I have not been able to figure out what I am missing.

I have a table that adds Actions to each row READ, UPDATE and DELETE buttons to perform CRUD actions on each row of data.

The buttons depend on data-form-url being set to the url and id, like the below, which then pop up in a modal.

```
<button type="button" id="read-file" class="inline-block bs-modal btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'read_file' fileupload.id %}">
   <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
</button>
```

This only works for the first 10 entries initialized in the table.  The buttons are dead for entries 11 and beyond, basically anything not initialized in the first view and paginated or hidden via the "show 10, 25, 50, 100 entries" dropdown.

Can someone help me understand why the buttons are not working and how to activate them again for paginated or hidden rows?

views.py

```
class FileUploadListView(generic.ListView):
   model = FileUpload
   context_object_name = 'fileuploads'
   template_name = 'fileupload/file-list-view.html'

   #Filter view for current user
   def get_queryset(self):
   """Returns FileUploads that belong to the current user"""
      return FileUpload.objects.filter(my_user=self.request.user)
```

html (for the file-table which is included into a base file)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered {% if fileuploads %}table-hover{% endif %}" id="file-table" style="font-size: small; width: 100%;">
<!--Table Head-->
<thead class="">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%;">#</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 25%;">File Name</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 40%;">Description</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Created</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Status</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 10%; text-align:center;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% if fileuploads %}
    <!--iterate page object-->
    {% for fileupload in fileuploads %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><span class="align-middle">{{ forloop.counter }}</span></th>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="align-middle">{{ fileupload.file_name }}</span></a></td>
        <td><span class="align-middle" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; display: inline-block; max-width: 400px;">{{ fileupload.file_description }}</span></td>
        <td><span class="align-middle">{{ fileupload.file_create_date|date:'M j, Y' }}</span></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            {% if fileupload.file_status == 'ready' %}
                <span class="align-middle" style="color: orange;">{{ fileupload.file_status|upper }}</span>
            {% else %}
                <span class="align-middle" style="color: green;">{{ fileupload.file_status|upper }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <!--Modal Trigger Elements-->
        <td class="inline-block" style="text-align:center;white-space: nowrap;">
            <!-- Read file buttons -->
            <button type="button" id="read-file" class="inline-block bs-modal btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'read_file' fileupload.id %}">
                <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Update file buttons -->
            <button type="button" id="update-file" class="inline-block bs-modal btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-form-url="{% url 'update_file' fileupload.id %}">
                <span class="fa fa-pencil-alt"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Delete file buttons -->
            <button type="button" id="delete-file" class="inline-block bs-modal btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-form-url="{% url 'delete_file' fileupload.id %}">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="p-5" style="text-align:center;">
            <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-3x" style="color:lightgrey;"></i>
            <h5 class="pt-3" style="color: lightgrey;">No Files Added Yet</h5>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
</tbody>
```

DataTable ZeroConfig Script

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {$('#file-table').DataTable();} );</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little playing around with it, I was able to figure out that in my script tag, the $(document).ready(function() needed to be placed below my modal scripts.  Once that change was made, all CRUD buttons on the rows became active again for hidden and paginated items.